# Rails warning message after clicking a 3rd party link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am trying to find a way to show a "You are navigating away from this site" message every time someone clicks on a link that takes them away from my site.

I know this can be done for individual links but is there a way to apply it to all links that don't begin with https://www.genericwebsite.com or http://www.genericwebsite.com?

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: You could run a piece of javascript that will look for all `<a>` tags and modify them on each page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by java script. http://www.codepotato.co.uk/2012/08/09/how-to-create-a-warning-when-opening-external-links-in-jquery/ answers your question.